# c# Accessing custom Settings File

Tags: c#

So I went in to the project and right click > Add and created a new Config.settings file and Login.settings file.

I then added a couple of inputs in each of those settings files.

How do go about accessing the settings values in those settings files?

I tried `Properties.Default...` but then it seems to not recognize `Properties` class as it shows a curly red underline in its name.

Do I have to import some name space?

I then try adding a new file called "Setting.settings" file and its still the same. I clean and rebuilt my project too.

Comment: What are you using? .net core? asp.net? asp.net core?

Comment: i am using .net 4.7

Comment: I am using a console application. I think the problem is I dont have a `settings.Design.cs` file which is auto generated. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Right click n settings file and select run custom tool

Comment: Especially when I want to have multiple `.settings` files how can one get access to these? I assume these settings file can be changed during run time so the application can in a sense take different user defined parameters after the entire app is released?

Comment: "Run Custom Tool" didn't do anything after clicking it

Comment: These settings you define here are defult ones. When user will be running app, he will have the settings.user file that will overwrite defaults with his values.

Comment: If you really want a custom settings file (title) you will need to write your own Settings Provider. Some of the assertions and expectations posted are not actually true.  A vanilla `UserOptions` class that you serialize is simpler for most custom needs

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on .settings file and selecting run custom tool option.

Also, sometimes it helps when you manually remove bin and obj files from project. Finally, close the solution and open again.

For user overrides and how settings are working refer to microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings